# How to configure Spring WebClient to reuse access tokens

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to use the spring `WebClient` to access some OAuth2 secured REST services. It works but it seems that it does not reuse the access token between requests. I started with password grant and refresh token and the refresh token was used to get a new access token with every request. Then I tried to use client credentials, since it seemed that not everything is supported with password grant type - but the behavior was the same, it requested a new access token on every request also the token is valid for 5 minutes. To make sure it is not some strange configuration in my application or an old bug, I created a new empty spring boot app with the current version 3.2.4 and the minimal dependencies:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
- org.springframework:spring-webflux
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test

I create the WebClient like that:

```
  @Bean
  WebClient webClient(
          WebClient.Builder builder,
          ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
          OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository ) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction( clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository );
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId( "khtest" );
    return builder.filter( oauth ).build();
  }
```

Then I use the in injected WebClient like this:

```
    String result = webClient.get()
            .uri( "http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/AI/groups" )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono( String.class )
            .block();
```

If I call this two times after another, I get the following logs:

```
start first REST call
2024-03-28T10:32:18.716+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [    Test worker] o.s.http.codec.FormHttpMessageWriter     : [97b84a4] Writing {grant_type=[client_credentials]}
2024-03-28T10:32:18.734+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [    Test worker] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [97b84a4] HTTP POST http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/realms/AI/protocol/openid-connect/token
2024-03-28T10:32:18.802+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [97b84a4] [6f5d4358] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.840+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : [97b84a4] [6f5d4358] Decoded [{access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2RGdhSXNRR0REVm44Tk9USlk2cElSRnNHMH (truncated)...]
2024-03-28T10:32:18.848+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [97b84a4] Cancel signal (to close connection)
2024-03-28T10:32:18.852+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.FormHttpMessageWriter     : [1cc1a157] Writing {grant_type=[client_credentials]}
2024-03-28T10:32:18.853+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1cc1a157] HTTP POST http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/realms/AI/protocol/openid-connect/token
2024-03-28T10:32:18.889+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1cc1a157] [1daa2410] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.891+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : [1cc1a157] [1daa2410] Decoded [{access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2RGdhSXNRR0REVm44Tk9USlk2cElSRnNHMH (truncated)...]
2024-03-28T10:32:18.891+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1cc1a157] Cancel signal (to close connection)
2024-03-28T10:32:18.892+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [74a74070] HTTP GET http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/AI/groups
2024-03-28T10:32:18.899+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [74a74070] [7085d850] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.901+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [74a74070] [7085d850] Decoded "[{"id":"c129933b-0270-43ac-85bf-050f7d7ca35a","name":"ai-keycloak-admin","path":"/ai-keycloak-admin" (truncated)..."
[{"id":"c129933b-0270-43ac-85bf-050f7d7ca35a","name":"ai-keycloak-admin","path":"/ai-keycloak-admin","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"c5d34304-95a0-4a33-808b-9224c207eeed","name":"business","path":"/business","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"c70e3556-e620-4a9e-86d3-220540930669","name":"business-readonly","path":"/business-readonly","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"6af3b23a-706c-4d42-9c80-37648e186c5e","name":"management","path":"/management","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}}]
finished first REST call
start second REST call immediately, access token should still be valid
2024-03-28T10:32:18.906+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [    Test worker] o.s.http.codec.FormHttpMessageWriter     : [12bcf7c6] Writing {grant_type=[client_credentials]}
2024-03-28T10:32:18.906+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [    Test worker] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [12bcf7c6] HTTP POST http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/realms/AI/protocol/openid-connect/token
2024-03-28T10:32:18.918+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [12bcf7c6] [2a2aae5b] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.919+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : [12bcf7c6] [2a2aae5b] Decoded [{access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2RGdhSXNRR0REVm44Tk9USlk2cElSRnNHMH (truncated)...]
2024-03-28T10:32:18.919+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [12bcf7c6] Cancel signal (to close connection)
2024-03-28T10:32:18.922+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.FormHttpMessageWriter     : [6b46d949] Writing {grant_type=[client_credentials]}
2024-03-28T10:32:18.923+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [6b46d949] HTTP POST http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/realms/AI/protocol/openid-connect/token
2024-03-28T10:32:18.939+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [6b46d949] [451c14d8] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.940+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : [6b46d949] [451c14d8] Decoded [{access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2RGdhSXNRR0REVm44Tk9USlk2cElSRnNHMH (truncated)...]
2024-03-28T10:32:18.941+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [6b46d949] Cancel signal (to close connection)
2024-03-28T10:32:18.941+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [3a116ca6] HTTP GET http://172.28.80.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/AI/groups
2024-03-28T10:32:18.949+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [3a116ca6] [2131e65a] Response 200 OK
2024-03-28T10:32:18.950+01:00 DEBUG 50808 --- [demo] [onPool-worker-1] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [3a116ca6] [2131e65a] Decoded "[{"id":"c129933b-0270-43ac-85bf-050f7d7ca35a","name":"ai-keycloak-admin","path":"/ai-keycloak-admin" (truncated)..."
[{"id":"c129933b-0270-43ac-85bf-050f7d7ca35a","name":"ai-keycloak-admin","path":"/ai-keycloak-admin","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"c5d34304-95a0-4a33-808b-9224c207eeed","name":"business","path":"/business","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"c70e3556-e620-4a9e-86d3-220540930669","name":"business-readonly","path":"/business-readonly","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}},{"id":"6af3b23a-706c-4d42-9c80-37648e186c5e","name":"management","path":"/management","subGroupCount":0,"subGroups":[],"access":{"view":true,"viewMembers":true,"manageMembers":true,"manage":true,"manageMembership":true}}]
finished second REST call
```

It looks like the application somehow makes not only one but two token requests for each REST call.

Looking at `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter`, I don't really get how it should work. It checks for an entry for `OAUTH2_AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_ATTR_NAME` in the requests attribute map but it seems that it is never filled, so it always calls `authorizeClient` but even if it was filled it would call `reauthorizeClient`, what looks like it will also result in a token request. I would have expected some check if the access token in the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` was still valid, but I haven't found something like that. I also looked at the reactive variant (`ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`), but I got  the same behavior there - and I'm not totally sure using the reactive version in a servlet application is a good idea.

I feel like I'm missing something here, any help is appreciated, thank you.